# SDL audio call back not working?

Tags: c, audio, sdl

I have the following snippet of codes. Where I need to get that audio samples and play them accordingly.

```
struct {
SDL_AudioSpec spec; /* SDL Audio Spec Structure */
Uint8 *sound; /* Pointer to wave data */
Uint32 soundlen; /* Length of wave data */
int soundpos; /* Current play position */
} wave;
```

Here is my call back function.

```
void fillerup(void *unused, Uint8 *stream, int len)
{
Uint8 *waveptr;
int waveleft=0;
printf("in fillerup");
waveptr = wave.sound + wave.soundpos;
waveleft = wave.soundlen - wave.soundpos;
    while ( waveleft <= len ) {
    /* Process samples */
    Uint8 *process_buf = (Uint8 *)malloc(waveleft * sizeof(Uint8));
    if(process_buf == 0) {
        // do something here
    }
    SDL_memcpy(process_buf, waveptr, waveleft);
    /* do processing here, e.g. */
    /* processing the audio samples in process_buf[*] */
    // play the processed audio samples
    SDL_memcpy(stream, process_buf, waveleft);
    stream += waveleft;
    len -= waveleft;
    // ready to repeat play the audio
    waveptr = wave.sound;
    waveleft = wave.soundlen;
    wave.soundpos = 0;
    free(process_buf);  
    }
}
```

In my main I have this codes.

```
if ( SDL_LoadWAV("file1.wav",&wave.spec, &wave.sound, &wave.soundlen) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load %s: %s\n", "file1.wav", SDL_GetError());
       //quit(1);
    }
    // set up the callback function
    wave.spec.callback = fillerup;
```

I have commented this codes as whenever I ope it gives me the error couldnt open audio. where as the top LOADWav gives me not error and check that the wav file do exist.

```
/*if ( SDL_OpenAudio(&wave.spec, NULL) < 0 ) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open audio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
                SDL_FreeWAV(wave.sound);
                //quit(2);
     }*/
     // start playing
     SDL_PauseAudio(0);
```

What could be the problem which does not do the callback ?

Comment: very simple audio player in c++ : https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/Wav_Audio_player_SDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never open the actual audio output device with `SDL_OpenAudio()`, then there isn't anything actually trying to *play* audio, so of course there's nothing that calls your buffer-filling callback.

If opening the audio device fails, then that's a problem you need to solve. The `SDL_LoadWav()` calls doesn't open a device, it fills in the spec so you can hand that to `SDL_OpenAudio()`.

Comment: @I want to understand what actually the callback suppose to do get each sample? So meaning that it get a stream of data that is analog? and do a sampling here?

Comment: @user2711681 SDL will call your callback when it needs more audio data, since during playback it will consume the data (by sending it to the speakers). Your application will run in the callback to generate more data, to keep the sound playing.

Comment: .wav is already in digital format am I correct ? So what will the callback do is get each of data bit or byte to play ?

Comment: I have managed to solve the SDL_openAudio issue but my file is less then a second but it calling my callback here is where I am lost? In my callback I have this line printf("in fillerup:%d",wave.soundlen); and it keep printing as in fillerup:8343?